# Deno.memoryUsage is returning heapTotal > resident set size (rss)

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, v8, deno

I'm currently having an issue where the rss returned from Deno.memoryUsage (across applications) is returning an rss size that is less than the heapTotal. This is an issue that just started in the past few days. Rss starts higher in some applications and then crosses below heapTotal in those applications. This is consistent across all Deno applications, regardless of any other frameworks used.

I'm using the Deno v. 1.27.2 on all the applications. This is an issue across multiple applications, computers, and developers (I'm working with a small team) and not specific to any particular tech stack.

My understanding based on every article I've read and from the Deno docs is that rss should represent the total memory of the process in RAM. It should include both the heapTotal and heapUsed and the call stack. My understanding is that it should never fall below heapTotal. This is the diagram I've seen everywhere:
[image: A diagram of memory in a JavaScript runtime environment]

Does anyone have any insight into this? Am I misunderstanding the resident set size (rss) entirely? Is the rss different in Deno than in Node?

What we've tried:

I've dug into the rust source code for Deno and found that they are using this rust function to measure the resident-set-size:

```
pub fn total_physical_size(&self) -\> usize {
   unsafe { v8__HeapStatistics__total_physical_size(self) }
}
```

Which retrieves the total_heap_size() from the v8 engine.

When we sampled the memory statistics after discovering the bug, we used the following function and ran it on multiple applications, always receiving the same result:

```
setInterval(() => {
   console.log(Deno.memoryUsage());
}, 500)
```

Here is a sampling of values we have received from one of our applications.

```
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3894252, external: 29347 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3906964, external: 33617 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3919676, external: 37887 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3932388, external: 42157 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3945100, external: 46427 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3957812, external: 50697 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3970524, external: 54967 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3983236, external: 59237 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3995948, external: 63507 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4008660, external: 67777 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4021372, external: 72047 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4034084, external: 76317 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4046796, external: 80587 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4059508, external: 84857 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4072220, external: 89127 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4084932, external: 93397 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4097644, external: 97667 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4110356, external: 101937 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4123088, external: 106209 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4135804, external: 110481 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4148520, external: 114753 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4161236, external: 119025 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4173952, external: 123297 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4186668, external: 127569 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4199384, external: 131841 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4212100, external: 136113 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4224816, external: 140385 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4237532, external: 144657 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4250248, external: 148929 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4262964, external: 153201 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4275680, external: 157473 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4288396, external: 161745 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4301112, external: 166017 }
{ rss: 4669440, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 4313828, external: 170289 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3869548, external: 20807 }
{ rss: 4423680, heapTotal: 4849664, heapUsed: 3882260, external: 25077 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of research shows that what Deno reports as "rss" is *not* the  resident set size of the process; it's the "committed" (as opposed to reserved) size of the managed heap. So it should always be more than `heapUsed` and always less than `heapTotal`, which matches the numbers you're getting.

Relevant part of Deno's [`core/ops_builtin_v8.rs`](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/core/ops_builtin_v8.rs#L667):

```rust
fn op_memory_usage(scope: &mut v8::HandleScope) -> MemoryUsage {
  let mut s = v8::HeapStatistics::default();
  scope.get_heap_statistics(&mut s);
  MemoryUsage {
    rss: s.total_physical_size(),
    ...
```

So it doesn't even attempt to measure what you and I call "RSS", it just incorrectly renames what V8 reports as "total physical size", which is the committed fraction of "total heap size".

---

For reference, when I start a fresh Deno 1.27.2 process and ask it for its memory usage, I get (in bytes, per the [documentation](https://deno.land/api@v1.27.2?s=Deno.MemoryUsage)):

```
{ rss: 3682304, heapTotal: 3862528, heapUsed: 3306952, external: 225 }
```

Letting that process sit and checking its actual RSS from another terminal:

```
$ ps -e | grep deno
3713179 pts/4    00:00:02 deno
$ cat /proc/3713179/status | grep VmRSS
VmRSS:    183028 kB
```

we see that actual RSS is at ~179 MB when Deno's "rss" reports 3.5 MB. You could file a bug against Deno if you care enough.

---

Side note: sampling the heap size every 500ms is pretty pointless. You only get useful new data after full GC cycles anyway, and those should be at least several seconds apart even on heavily loaded applications (maybe aside from microbenchmarks that stress test very specific allocation patterns). I wouldn't sample the heap size more often than once a minute or so.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful. We actually dug into the Deno source code yesterday and I found that exact function (i.e. total_physical_size) in the v8 engine, and that didn't seem to be a measure of rss based on the v8 docs. I just wasn't knowledgeable enough to confirm that suspicion. We did file that bug on their github seeing as how they are improperly labeling their memory statistics which will cause issues in production. I'll include your research in our ticket and modify our application. 

To the side note: we were only measuring that quickly to sample the error!

Comment: @mksnooty Could you link that github issue here as well, please?

Comment: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/16581